# Use GCC11 on (K)ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, gcc11

I want to use some new C ++ 20 functions that are implemented in the as-yet-unreleased GCC-11. I tried installing the package on Ubuntu 20.04 but as expected it doesn't exist yet. The web search didn't come up with anything useful either.

Is there any way to use GCC-11 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes - compile from sources.

Comment: @KamilCuk Never done this before. Is there a guide somewhere?

Comment: @Silicomancer: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html

Comment: I also like doing it like so: take the package _build sources_ for older version ex. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gcc-10 , bump up the version in build files and source location there and build the package. It's sometimes much easier to do because it already tracks build dependencies and builds a ready-to-use package that is easy to uninstall.

Comment: Someone set -1, why?

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution via ppa.

You can find the instructions here:
[Install g++ 11 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://lindevs.com/install-g-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: I flagged this for [deletion](/help/deleted-answers) because it consists almost entirely of a link. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259): add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable. If you [edit] this answer to add more once it is deleted, please flag it for moderator attention so that it can be un-deleted.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31281182)

Comment: From the page linked, the PPA in question: 
`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`